# How do I create an exception on before update/insert where I have to compare value of attribute of one table to the value of the attribute of another?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, sql-update

Schema is

CUSTOMER(Cus_code, Cus_fname, Cus_lname, Cus_balance)

INVOICE(Inv_no, Cus_code, Inv_date, Inv_amount)

LINE(Inv_no, Line_no, P_code, Line_units, Line_price)

PRODUCT(P_code, P_desc, P_qoh, P_min, P_price, V_code)

VENDOR(V_code, V_name, V_Contact)

```
create or replace trigger inexcb
before update 
of invoice.Inv_amount,customer.cus_balance
on invoice,customer  
for each row
when (invoice.Inv_amount>customer.cus_balance)
where invoice.cus_balance=customer.cus_balance
declare
excep1 exception;
begin
raise excep1;
dbms_output.put_line='Invoice amount becoming more than Customer balance is 
not allowed.';
end;
```

Comment: This won't even compile.  dbms_output.put_line is a procedure call, ie

Comment: Surely _'Invoice amount cannot exceed Customer balance.'_

Comment: For custom error use something like  `raise_application_error(-20000,'Invoice amount .. blah blah blah');`

Comment: Now regarding your 'trigger code'... on which table exactly this trigger is supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> create or replace function inv_detail(inv_num char)
  2  return number is
  3  cus_bal number(6,2);
  4  begin
  5  select c.cus_balance into cus_bal from customer c
  6  where c.cus_code=inv_num;
  7  return cus_bal;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace trigger thr_exce
  2  before insert on invoice
  3  for each row
  4  begin
  5  if :new.Inv_amount>inv_detail(:new.cus_code) then
  6  raise_application_error(-20200,'Invoice amount cannot be greater than customer balance');
  7  end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Well I just submitted my assignment with this without bothering about raising a real exception(due to the constraint of time) but guess that's it.